# Display 3 buttons in a row IN a scroll view

Tags: android, button, view, scrollview

at the moment I have a list of **buttons** showing up in a `ScrollView` however all the buttons are on the left hand side and go down in one column.

I would like these buttons to be shown in columns of 3, so 3 buttons in one row when I add row dynamically

Here is the current code I have to display these buttons

```
 // Find the ScrollView
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)   
   findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

// Create a LinearLayout element
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// Add Buttons


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText("Some text");
            linearLayout.addView(button);
        }
    }


 // Add the LinearLayout element to the ScrollView
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

     }
```

I tried setting layout parameters for the buttons however it didn't change anything

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: please check the answer I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic

```
// Find the ScrollView
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

// Create a LinearLayout element
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// Add Buttons


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
     LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = new LinearLayout(this);
     linearLayoutChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
     linearLayoutChild.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          Button button = new Button(this);
          button.setText("Some text");
          linearLayoutChild.addView(button);
        }
     linearLayout.addView(linearLayoutChild);
    }

 // Add the LinearLayout element to the ScrollView
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
```

### Unless and until it is required I will prefer GridView or RecyclerView over Dynamic view adding